# Getting the name of a Clojure struct type?

Tags: struct, clojure

When defining a struct type and instance, I can print the value and get the "struct" implementation type:

```
(defstruct person :name :age)
(def p (struct person "peter" 30))

user=> p
{:name "peter", :age 30}
user=> (type p)
clojure.lang.PersistentStructMap
```

But is it possible to tell whether p is an instance of the struct type "person"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See: [this post in the Clojure Google Group.](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/a5e0ba6480d04829/3fbd539b807a506d?q=struct+type+group:clojure#3fbd539b807a506d)
In general the group archives are a treasure chest...

Note: The functionality of structs is replaced by records. Then this is not a problem anymore, because records really define new type and you can check with `instance?` whether something is of record of a certain type.

Comment: OK, thanks. Records seems to be the way to go - just need to upgrade Clojure.

Comment: Well. 1.2 is not released, yet. So YMMV.

Comment: Clojure 1.2 is now released...  And hadn't come across YMMV before - a phrase I may use in future!!

Answer (score 4):

A bit ugly, but it works:

```
(require '[clojure.contrib.java-utils :as cj])

(defn struct-instance? [struct-def sm]
  (= (cj/wall-hack-field clojure.lang.PersistentStructMap "def" sm)
     struct-def))

(struct-instance? person p)
; => true

(struct-instance? person (conj p [:foo 1] [:bar 2]))
; => true

(defstruct foo :k1 :k2)
(struct-instance? foo p)
; => false
```

Stuff from `clojure.contrib.java-utils` will be available in 1.2 in part in `clojure.java`, in part in `clojure.contrib.java` (I guess?), and also in `clojure.contrib.java-utils` for backward compatibility... Although the details might still change. At any rate, Meikel is right about `defrecord` replacing `defstruct`, so if you're working on 1.2, prefer that.

Comment: You certainly seem to know your way around Clojure ;)
I'm at 1.1 for the moment, but the 1.2 defrecord looks like a better long-term solution. Still, thanks for the hack and the pointer to java-utils :)